# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed after reseting migrations

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models

I need to save an object that contains a file and some other data. Although the file is stored on the /media folder, the entity is not saved in the database since saving it triggers an integration error.

django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: app_eeg.filename

'filename' was a field I deleted and I already deleted the migrations folder and did the following commands:

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations app
python3 manage.py migrate app
```

Models.py

```
class EEG(models.Model):

    file = models.FileField(null=False)                                     
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)                     
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    report = models.ForeignKey(Report, verbose_name=('report'), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='%(class)s_report', null=True)
    operator = models.ForeignKey(Operator, verbose_name=('operator'), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='%(class)s_operator', null=False)
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, verbose_name=('patient'), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='%(class)s_patient', null=False)
```

How can I fix this error from happening?

Comment: Did you change your model, apply it's migration to your DB, then revert the change and delete the migration file? Now you want to roll-back the changes made to the DB by the migration that you have deleted? Can you afford to lose the data in your DB by just recreating it fresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the column from the table manually by connecting to the database
and execute the SQL statement:

`ALTER TABLE app_eeg DROP COLUMN filename;`